# Vue production build empty page even though assets are loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My vue production build (built with `npm run build`) delivers a styled (the background color from my css is applied) blank page.

If I check the page source I see that the js code is properly loaded, but my `app` div is still empty.

What can be the source of that?

Comment: any errors in browser console? the issue could be a few things

Comment: check for warnings in the console in dev mode

Comment: Neither in dev mode, nor in the production console there are errors...

Comment: try to add the property: "publicPath" to your vue.config.js or "base" property to your vite.config.js

Comment: Nope, still the same :(

Comment: Hard to help without any actual code. It's a "guessing game". Can you show us your vue.config.js or maybe add a minimal reproducable code so we can debug it on our side?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578498/vue-webpack-build-show-blank-page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it didn't show anything, bc I'm hosting the page static in an AWS S3 Bucket. Setting the vue router history mode to  `history: createWebHashHistory()` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use lazy loading of the route, but did not catch the loading exception?check the router view first!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly I need to check?